# Math equation to create a layout for photoset-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am using a jQuery plugin 'photoset-grid' to create photoset of images. 
This is a link to the plugin:
http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/

```
    $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
        layout: '132',
        width: '90%',
        gutter: '4px'
    });

<div class="photoset-grid">
  <img src="img/1.jpg">
  <img src="img/2.jpg">
  <img src="img/3.jpg">
  <img src="img/4.jpg">
  <img src="img/5.jpg">
  <img src="img/6.jpg">
</div>
```

The code above create a layout of images based on the assigned value to layout 
`layout: "132"` 1st row has 1 image, 2nd row has 3 images, and 3rd row has 2 images.

My concern is that I am using this as a standard for all 
`<div class="photoset-grid">` and the number of images differ on each set, how can I create a function or equation that based on the total number of images, say for example 5 images returns a random layout that fits the total number of images `layout: "122"`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** -- Since images are dynamycally added by user...


I made you a *starter demo* to show that my previous answer was not bad at all.
But to re-instantiate photosetGrid, sadly... You have to trash it.
(using `.remove()` and, then, `.clone()` the uninstantiated `div` which contains the pictures).

**It's just a starter that you will have to study...**
And try something with.
I won't create a full function to your taste for free.

Have a look at this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MpNPrX?editors=0010).
I strongly suggest that you squeeze the display panel to see all images beeing dynamically added.

I won't copy the code here...
Since this is an unperfect demo using the previous answer.
You should get the idea if you put the effort.
The code is well commented and I left my debug `console.log()`.
;)

---

You could use a `data` attribute and use `.each()` to initiate them all differently.
*(it would save you the math!)*

Something like this:

```
$('.photoset-grid').each(function(){
  $(this).photosetGrid({
    layout: $(this).data("layout"),
    width: '90%',
    gutter: '4px'
  });
});
```

```
<!-- One layout for 6 images -->
<div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="132">
  <img src="img/1.jpg">
  <img src="img/2.jpg">
  <img src="img/3.jpg">
  <img src="img/4.jpg">
  <img src="img/5.jpg">
  <img src="img/6.jpg">
</div>

<!-- Another layout for 6 images -->
<div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="222">
  <img src="img/1.jpg">
  <img src="img/2.jpg">
  <img src="img/3.jpg">
  <img src="img/4.jpg">
  <img src="img/5.jpg">
  <img src="img/6.jpg">
</div>

<!-- one layout for 4 images -->
<div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="13">
  <img src="img/1.jpg">
  <img src="img/2.jpg">
  <img src="img/3.jpg">
  <img src="img/4.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: That's the thing this wont work with me as Its auto generated when the user add images I wont let the user assign the layout.

Comment: That was not mentionned in your question!!! And it complicates things. Once Photoset is instantiated, another attemps to instantiate it again with pictures appended just does nothing (it won't update, I just tested it) and it doesn't look to be a `destroy` method... So, there *may* be a possibility to do something via clonage... Let me think.

Comment: I made you a demo for dynamic picture add.